# In "The Day of the Doctor" who else goes out from the Picture?

Tags: doctor-who, character-identification, gallifrey

I believe 5 people leave the Gallifrey Falls picture,
but I dont know who the five people were.

Comment: You should watch the episode again, since you've evidently slept through approximately 50% of it. ;)

Comment: Daleks are not people...are they?

Comment: @tilley31 Whoa, whoa, whoa. Daleks have feelings too.

Comment: Is EXTERMINATE!! a feeling though?

Comment: Eh...after last saturday's big reveal, as I wondered how it happened, I remembered this exact question. Can't really say it clear without spoiler tags, but maybe somebody else thought about this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was really looking forward to an explanation in the series 8 finale, but there wasn't. This is pure speculation, and it might be explained in the future, or never mentioned again. This is Doctor Who, after all...

[image: Screehshot from The Day Of The Doctor]

Some people (me included) have theorized that this is not Clara's hand, but

> Missy's

If this is right, then the five people to get out of the Gallifrey falls painting would be:

The Eleventh Doctor, The Tenth Doctor, The War Doctor, Clara

And...

> Missy / The Master

Now, if this was the plan all along, it should have been explained in the Series 8 finale, but it wasn't. So take it like it is: a fan theory.